# Fortran: Accessing values from the return type of a function

Tags: fortran, operator-overloading

I have created a derived type V, and included an add function
so that I can use the operator +.

However when I do

```
z = u + v
```

the operation is not performed. I think it is because `z%kn` 
is not being accessed.

However when I do

```
Call vsum(z, u, v)
```

everything works as expected

Below is the declaration of the derived type and the 
overloading function vadd.

```
Module vtest

Type :: V

  Character (Len=8) :: kn
  Real,  Allocatable :: vc(:)

  Contains

    Procedure :: vadd
    Generic :: Operator (+) => vadd

 End Type vtest

Contains

Function vadd (b, c) Result (a)
  Type (V) :: a
  Class (V), Intent (In) :: b, c

  !!$ In vsum, use is made of a% kn 
  Call vsum (a, b, c)

End Function vadd

 Subroutine vsum (ta, tb, tc)
   Type (V), Intent (InOut)  :: ta
   Type (V), Intent (In) :: tb, tc

   Logical :: la, lb, lc

   la = .False.;  lb = .False.;  lc = .False.

   Select Case (ta%kn) 

   Case ("Real32")
     If (Allocated (ta%vc)) la = .True.
     If (Allocated (tb%vc)) lb = .True.
     If (Allocated (tc%vc)) lc = .True.
     If (la .And. lb .And. lc) Then 
       ta%vc = tb%vc + tc%vc
     End If

   End Select

 End Subroutine vsum

End Module vtest


Program test
Use vtest
Type (V) :: z

   z% kn = "Real32"
   Allocate (z% vc_real32(3))
   Write (*,*) "z = u + v"
   Write (*,*) "z% kn: ", z% kn
   z = u + v
   Write (*,*) "z% kn: ", z% kn
   Write (*,*) "z: ", z% vc_real32

End Program vtest
```

Comment: Please show your code for `vsum`.

Comment: The code is still incomplete. Hardly a mcve http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve It is missing the operator invocation and its surroundings. There can be a bug in any detail you haven't shown. You should prepare a fully compilable code. Include the output of your code. How did you diagnose that the operation is not performed? What happened instead than?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the subroutine `vsum`.  The work that is done in that subroutine depends on the definition of the components of all three objects `ta`, `tb` and `tc`.  For your summation to proceed as you expect it is necessary for all the allocatable components to be allocated and for the match of `ta%kn` with `'Real32'`.

There's no complete working example, but as you say things work when there is a call like

```
call vsum(z, u, w)  ! V is the name of the type, so call the variable w
```

`z%kn` is set to `'Real32'`.

However, with the defined operation

```
z = u + w
```

there is the function reference

```
z = vadd(u, w)
```

in which there is the call

```
call vsum (a, b, c)  ! Actual arguments "z", u, w.
```

Now, `a` is the function result of `vadd`.  Consequent of this is that, just like a dummy argument with `intent(out)` `a` is initially undefined.

That means, essentially, when passed through `vadd` `z` makes it to `vsum` with undefined component `kn` and unallocated component `vc`.  So, the requirements for the summation are not met (and indeed the `select case` forms an invalid reference).

---

I suppose I can comment on how to fix this issue, also.

In `vsum`, you're taking, in effect, the type of operation from the "result".  Instead, something like

```
Subroutine vsum (ta, tb, tc)
  Type (V), Intent (Out)  :: ta
  Type (V), Intent (In) :: tb, tc

  Logical :: lb, lc

  lb = .False.;  lc = .False.

  ! In here we probably want some consistency checking...
  Select Case (tb%kn)    
  Case ("Real32")
    If (Allocated (tb%vc)) lb = .True.
    If (Allocated (tc%vc)) lc = .True.
    If (lb .And. lc) Then 
      ta%vc = tb%vc + tc%vc   ! ta%vc being automatically allocated
    End If
  End Select

 End Subroutine vsum
```

This, naturally, doesn't address your seeming desire (from the title) to take the type of operation from the result.  You *could* do that with your original subroutine approach, but except in one instance that isn't the philosophy of Fortran functions.

If you want to use defined operations, then you can't have the operation defined by the left-hand side of the assignment.  In an expression `u+w` there isn't a left-hand side, but the defined operation is still expected to behave.  That is also to say, in the statement

```
z = u + w
```

you aren't saying "`z` is the result of the operation `+` applied to `u` and `w`".  But: "the operation `+` applied to `u` and `w` is evaluated and the result (through defined or implicit assignment) assigned to `z`".  There is that assignment before the "type of the result" is reached.  This is why earlier on I put `z` as the actual argument in quotes.

Comment: +1 Especially for the last paragraph. Fortran functions never "look" what is on the left hand side of the assignment. They don't have to be placed in an assignment at all! They compute some expression and that expression is than used somehow by the calling code.

Comment: That means, essentially, when passed through vadd z makes it to vsum with undefined component kn and unallocated component vc. So, the requirements for the summation are not met (and indeed the select case forms an invalid reference). --- This is exactly what is happening.

Comment: Have tried your modification, however I am still not getting the result correctly returned. Have printed the array values after calling 'vsum' in the function 'vadd' and I get the correct values. However in the the main program the result outputted is still undefined.

Comment: You mean that after the call in `vadd` that `a` has the correct values but those aren't then passed to `z`?  That doesn't make much sense to me, but I do see that your main program presented isn't quite right: the right hand side variables aren't defined (and one still badly named).